# How do I import components into my App.js file

Tags: reactjs

All element rendered in my **App.js** file are no displaying on my webpage

After I created both functional and class components separately then using `<FunctionalComponents/>` to import them into my **App.js** files they are both not showing up on my web page, All element displaying on my web page are in the **index.js** file, How do I fix this

Comment: Show your folder structure.

Comment: import ClassComponents from './Components/ClassComponents';
import FunctionalComponents from './Components/FunctionalComponents';

function App() {
    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <FunctionalComponents/>
            <ClassComponents/>
    
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;

Comment: Is this the right folder structure?

Comment: I'm a beginner, sorry